# Dereference struct array in thread function?

Tags: c, arrays, multithreading, struct

I am passing pointer to an array of structs to thread function.

```
pthread_create(&init_thread, NULL, initialize, reservations);
```

Later, I am not sure how to dereference it inside thread function.

reservations is

```
struct reservation reservations[20]
```

an array of struct.

thread function is initialize as below.

```
void * initialize(void * args) {
  struct reservation *all_reservations[] = (struct reservation *[])args;

  // Wait for semaphore signals
  sem_wait(mutexA);
  sem_wait(mutexB);

  for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    if (all_reservations[i]) {
      all_reservations[i] = NULL;
    }
  }
  // Signal semaphores for other processes
  sem_signal(mutexA);
  sem_signal(mutexB);

  printf("%s\n","All reservations are initialized.");
}
```

I am getting this error:
error: cast to incomplete type 'struct reservation *[]'

Answer (score 2):

Remember that arrays decays to pointers to their first element.

So when you pass the argument `reservations` to the `pthread_create` call, it's actually the same as `&reservations[0]`, which is of type `struct reservation *`. Which is the type you should use in the thread function.

In other words, in the thread function `initialize` you don't have an array of pointers, but just a plain pointer to the first *element* of an array of structures. Each element is of type `struct reservation`, i.e. not pointers.

---

Besides that, I fail to see the use of a thread for a simple initialization of the `reservations` array. What it does (initialize each structure) must be done before any other processing can be done, so it's inherently *serial*. It *must* be done before anything else, there's no need or even use for any kind of parallel work.

Answer (score 1):

The argument you passed, `reservations`, is not a pointer to an array. It is an array, which passed as a function argument goes as a pointer to the first element.

You can cast and declare as a simple pointer:

```
struct reservation *all_reservations = (struct reservation *)args;
```